# RDLC Chart... remove series

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, report, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to use a Report item in Visual Studio 2012 to generate a chart based upon a populated dataset.

I have the following columns in my dataset table:

```
date

usersvalue

averagevalue
```

(among others, but these are what I want to show in the chart.)

I start with a blank report, set the data source, and add a generic line chart:
[image: generic chart]

Note that this starts with two series (`Series 1` and `Series 2`) listed.  I cannot find where these are specified in any property page I look at.  I want my `usersvalue` and my `averagevalue` to be my data point series, with the `date` value being the x axis.  If I add these values to the series, however, it creates 4 lines on the chart, a Series 1 and Series 2 for both the `usersvalue` and `averagevalue`.

I don't consider myself a dummy.  I can do this in Crystal Reports and Excel with no issues.  I have been trying to figure out how to just show two lines with the info I want for hours now.  Either I am missing something painfully obvious or this is the most unintuitive reports system I have ever had the misfortune of encountering.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is in the series group, there you should give the grouping paramenter that could be the userID, and in the values you put the to fields usersvalue and averagevalue(but I think you already did this). Hope this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the following:

[image]

Create first a dataset named "dstest"  and make a datatable with "dttest" and fill with data as in figure

[image]

```
make a report file (eg. test.rdlc) and drag/drop a line chart as figure
add the dataset "dstest" along with rdlc that we have created before.
```

[image]
[image]
    add "values", "category groups" and "series group"  as in figure. with "Values","X" and "Y"
[image]

add a windows form and drag/drop a report viewer in it.
 on form load write following codes:

```
private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        dtt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(string));
        dtt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(string));
        dtt.Columns.Add("Values", typeof(int));

        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/26/2014", "uservalue", 10 });
        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/25/2014", "uservalue", 14 });
        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/24/2014", "uservalue", 9 });

        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/26/2014", "averagevalue", 15 });
        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/25/2014", "averagevalue", 16 });
        dtt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/24/2014", "averagevalue", 7 });


        ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("dstest", dtt);   // dstest is dataset that you have added when creating rdlc
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "you path of rdlc file"\test.rdlc";

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

finally try running and loading form.
 you form should show following result..
[image]